# PHP,sql, UTF-8 encoding

Tags: php, sql, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to understand some problem at the UTF-8 encoding at the forum i am building,
For start, I am using:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

and:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

So the xml encoding is **utf-8** and same is for the **meta charset**, also the files i am working with is **UTF-8** and inside the Notepad++ it is **UTF-8 without BOM**, at the sql server the database and the tables are **utf8_general_ci**,

**The problem** is when i am inserting the data from the php code i see the data ok at the browser but weird at the sql server,

**when i inserting** the data from the sql server i see the data ok at the sql server but weird at the browser, If anyone know something please i will be very thankful.

Comment: Have you `SET NAMES 'utf8'` ? You can do this with `mysql_set_charset("utf8")` or `$db->set_charset("utf8")` before making any queries

Comment: use this in php `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` plus adding @Esailija query after connection directly, assuming you are using mysql

Comment: Thank you i shoulded set the charset at the connection same is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361459/php-pdo-charset-set-names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of sql server do you use?
I case of postgres or mysql, you should define
the tables and or the fields as utf-8 aware.

Otherwise, when the db was filled via csv and the data
inside are not utf-8 encoded, the result on your pages
will be then also not utf-8 encoded.

In that case, you can transform the characterset manually.

Answer (score 1):

$db = mysql_connect(...);

/* change character set to utf8 */
    mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8 ');

Simples!