# £ sign appearing as � when retrieved by sql and echoed

Tags: php, sql, char

I have a TEXT column in my SQL database that contains a £ char in it. I retrieve this column via an sql query and echo it as such:

```
echo "<div id=\"styler\">$textNote</div>";
```

But this £ sign appears as � on the page. The rest of the text appears normally.

If I manually input a £ sign on the page like this:

```
<p>£</p>
```

it appears normally.

How can I solve this?

Comment: The easiest answer is to replace `£` with `&pound;`. Before it goes into the DB. The more difficult answer is to make sure your input, storage, and output encodings are all playing nicely.

Comment: Have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816330/php-sql-utf-8-encoding

Comment: make sure database have uft8_encoding and html has utf too, and if you use htmlspecialchars for encoding to html

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>
```