# Why do I have to use utf8_decode before I insert an already UTF8 string in mysql?

Tags: php, json, utf-8

I am running into a problem, that I managed to fix by simply trying different options, but I don't understand why it works, it does not make sense to me...

Here it is, I receive UTF8 encoded JSON from Facebook, my table is in utf8_general_ci and my DB connection is UTF8 encoded too.

If I don't do anything special, the string is inserted as

> FabiÃ©n

but if I utf8_decode it before inserting it is inserted as

> Fabién

When I call mb_detect_encoding on my string, it returns UTF8.

Can anyone explain why I have to use utf8_decode for it to work? Or better, what to do to fix my code so I don't have to call utf8_decode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the table's encoding latin1?

Comment: It just looks like your viewing the table data as latin1.

Comment: No, the charset is utf8 as well. I created all my tables with the charset utf8 and collation utf8_general_ci. It's in phpmyadmin that I see the 2 examples from the question. Is there a way to change the encoding of the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, you have to execute the command "SET NAMES utf8" after establishing the connection to the DB with PDO. I am using an older version of PHP (5.3.6), and charset=utf8 is ignored in the connection string...

See this question: [PHP PDO: charset, set names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361459/php-pdo-charset-set-names)

Answer (score 1):

If your database/table/field is **utf8_general_ci** and the string is **UTF-8**, you should not convert the string before insert it.

You should select from the database and before printing in HTML, you should convert from UTF-8 to Latin1 (iso-8859-1) using this code:

```
 mb_convert_encoding($selected_string, 'utf-8', 'iso-8859-1')
```