# utf-8 charset with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, utf-8

Im trying to display some Indian language characters (Hindi, Tamil, etc) in a php file, taking the data from a MYSQL database.

It works fine with `mysqli_query`, but with PDO, the characters show up as garbage values. I am not able to figure out why, as I have set every possible aspect to work with `utf-8`.

**Here is my connection string :** (I am using **PHP version 5.6.8**)

```
$db_connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8;', 'username', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
```

After doing some research I discovered the `utf8_decode` function, and decided to try that. It works only partially, however.

These are the results (as labeled)

```
PDO result without utf8 decoding:
à¤†à¤œ à¤¸à¤¦à¥€à¤“ à¤•à¥‡ à¤¬à¤¾à¤¦ à¤–à¥à¤¦à¤•à¥‹ à¤¹à¤® à¤¸à¤‚à¤­à¤¾à¤²à¥‡ à¤¹à¥à¤... 

PDO result with utf8 decoding:
��?��? सद��?��? ��?��? बाद ��?ुद��?��? हम स��?भाल��? हुए... 

MYSQLI_QUERY:
आज सदीओ के बाद खुदको हम संभाले हुए...
```

Since only PDO is having this problem, I'm assuming my DB and headers are fine. Please let me know if any more code is needed (Queries are standard DB calls).

**EDIT:** I have done the following steps already, with regards to `utf-8` settings :

1. Setting DSN - `charset=utf8;`
2. Adding it to PDO's options array - `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'`
3. Setting it via PDO object's `exec` function :

`$db_connection->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
$db_connection->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");`

Comment: Make sure every part of your chain is expecting utf-8. Here's is a guide: http://www.toptal.com/php/a-utf-8-primer-for-php-and-mysql

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response! This is the guide that I used to get to this point :) I have followed every step given there already :(

Comment: Did you do `SET NAMES utf-8` as well?

Comment: Yes I did, using the `exec` function of my PDO object right? I also added it into the options array of the connection string itself (In the code above)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042474/pdo-connection-utf-8-declaration-with-set-names-character-set

Comment: Thanks saty, I saw that one too. Pretty much the same as the primer that @Halcyon shared :) I have already done all of these steps

Comment: I have added in an EDIT that explains what I've tried already, a bit clearer :)

Comment: Are you sure that the data in your database is actually correctly stored?! If so, how have you confirmed that? A *very typical* problem is that the data in the database is actually hosed, since it was inserted with incorrect encoding settings on the database connection before.

Comment: Look at the results that I posted above. It works perfectly with `mysql_query` and `mysqli_query`, which is why I figured my encoding in the DB and my php headers are fine

Comment: How did you set your encoding in mysql/mysqli before?

Comment: Please see the duplicate, this is most likely your problem. Investigate that. If it's not, add some new insights to your question to clarify.

Comment: Thank you @deceze, the solution you provided seems to work. PDO is now working fine, but `mysql_query` has stopped working. Not that it is of concern, but is there any particular reason why?

Comment: Because you're setting the wrong charset in your mysql function. You need to configure the connection charset for PDO, mysql and mysqli independently.

Comment: Also, I just realised that if I remove all `utf-8` settings and change it to `latin1`, it works without a hitch. Even though these are clearly utf-8 characters...

Comment: Read this: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/), it explains this in detail.

Comment: Ouch!  Using `latin1` only hides the problem, it does not solve it.  And comparisons will not work correctly -- LIKE, >, etc.

Comment: Please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...` so we can see if the text was stored correctly.  Also provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.