# Insert tulip character to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, special-characters

How can I insert the [tulip symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%F0%9F%8C%B7&redirect=no) () into the table column.

I am using PHP 5.3.x and using PDO for db operations, I tried setting various charsets like utf8, utf8mb4 but no use. When I use utf8 it said "Incorrect string value..."
and while using utf8mb4 tulip symbol was replaced to "?".

I tried all these options [PHP PDO: charset, set names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361459/php-pdo-charset-set-names)

```
$sql = new PDO(MySQL::DRIVER . ":host=host;dbname=db;charset=utf8",
                            MYSQL_USER,
                            MYSQL_PASSWORD,
                            array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")); // or utf8mb44
$sql->exec("set names utf8"); // or utf8mb44
$sql->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8"); // or utf8mb44
```

Comment: `utf8mb4` looks like what you want. Where does the symbol come from, how are you encoding it?

Comment: I get from this site https://foursquare.com/kbells130. there you could find name "Kaylya<symbol>". I do scrape it and send it to db without encoding anything. since i don want encode it.

Comment: FYI, this symbol can be visible in IE10. chrome & firefox shows it as a square.

Comment: @codelover I'm looking at that symbol right now in FF20/windows.

Comment: @jimmy anyhw pls help me to fix

Comment: @codelover could it be that your browser isn't displaying it correctly, even though the database can store it? if you run phpmyadmin for example, in IE10, is there a difference?

Comment: I could see only '?' (utf8mb4) when I see it in phpmyadmin thru IE10 or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP file you're sending it the character in needs to be encoded as UTF-8, and of course the database table needs to be `utf8mb4` as Adder points out.

Also, your database connection needs to be explicitly set to `utf8mb4` - why not do that straight away when connecting to the database?

```
$sql = new PDO(MySQL::DRIVER . ":host=host;dbname=db;charset=utf8mb4", ...
```

Essentially, the advice given in [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170) applies - just replace `utf8` by `utf8mb4` on mySQL's side.

Comment: I have included ;charset=utf8mb4" still symbol got replaced to "?". My table's & col's charset are utf8mb4

Comment: @codelover have you checked your file? What happens if you output the symbol from your file into the browser - do you see the right character?

Comment: It prints "\ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8".

Comment: Well, that's your problem then. Why is it in that form? What exactly is your code?

Comment: My code is just read the txt frm a webpage(like scraping) and sends it to database. while reading txt I got such chars :(

Comment: You'll need to add more info about what you're doing, and show some code. There's no way for the character to show up in that form unless you're doing something to it (like `json_encode()`)

Comment: Just how could I scrape your name"Pekka 웃" frm this page and store it in db as it is? thats wat I want.:)