# bogus chars in database despite utf8

Tags: database, utf-8, character-encoding, innodb

I have a large html form, which is submitted to a script and then data is entered into database.

For some reason my entered chars in database are not correct. **It turn ä into `Ã¤`**

The files are the following:

**page_varaa.php** which includes the form **form_haeverkkotunnus_data.php** or if form is submitted, it does the database action.

The both php pages are encoded as UTF-8 without BOM, have a

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

on top of the page. The table itself has collation

```
utf8_unicode_ci
```

and on the index.php page I have

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
```

I am using the msqli and enter the data like this into database:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute()
```

Database engine is innoDB

My database has a server connection colation of utf8_general_ci

Despite all this still I have bogus chars in database. What am I missing here?

Thank you so much

**edit:**

I triet to set table utf8_general_ci also, did not change anything :(

Comment: you need to set the connection to the database to use utf8, too. See this answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4361485/401704

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much cypherabe, I am not using PDO but your comment gave me the right direction, I had to set the charset for mysqli, like here;

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php