# query not working on script but works on phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is the code:

```
$paramater = "@CityNameWithñ";

$stmt = $connection->prepare("
    SELECT `col1`,`col2`
    FROM `table` 
    WHERE MATCH (`col3`,`col4`)
    AGAINST ( ? IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    AND `status` = 'a'");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$parameter);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($r1,$r2);
while($stmt->fetch()){
    var_dump($r1);
}
```

The above doesn't return anything. But if `$parameter` has a value of for example `@CityName` it works. I think the `ñ` is the one causing the problem?

I tried it in phpMyAdmin

```
    SELECT `col1`,`col2`
    FROM `table` 
    WHERE MATCH (`col3`,`col4`)
    AGAINST ( '@CityNameWithñ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    AND `status` = 'a'
```

It works. It returned 980 results.

Any idea what is making it fail in my query?

Comment: Where is the code where the MySQL variable @CityNameWithin gets set in PHP? The MySQL variable is probably not being carried because the PHP MySQL connection is different.

Comment: @virmaior a `var_dump()` on `$parameter` just before the `bind_param` returns a string with a value `@CityNameWithñ` and the connection is ok. Again like mentioned above the script works if the value of `$parameter` does not have `ñ` but returns nothing if it does have an `ñ`.

Comment: what is the connection charset for your PHP code vs phpmyadmin?

Comment: What is the file encoding? It can be a reason to missing result/

Comment: The table and its columns are `utf8_unicode_ci` and when I pass `$parameter` to `mb_detect_encoding()` it returns `utf8`

Comment: try to use  AGAINST ( '?' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

Comment: NOT the PHP encoding setting. The PHP MySQL connector encoding setting. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361459/php-pdo-charset-set-names

Comment: I think you should use utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments and some more searching I found out that the problem was a `charset` problem.

adding `$connection->set_charset("utf8")` to the script after establishing the mysqli connection helped.

Thanks!