# PDO fetchAll returning empty array, but rowCount does return the real result

Tags: php, json, pdo

I have this code:

```
    $json = array();
$hoy = date("Y-m-d");
$consulta = "SELECT e.*,s.sal_nombre, concat(eve_titulo, ' - ',sal_nombre) as title FROM evento e, sala s where s.sal_id=e.sal_id ORDER BY id";

// conexión bbdd
try {
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba2', 'root', '');
} catch(Exception $e) {
exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}

//ejecutamos consulta
$resultado = $bdd->query($consulta) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));

// enviamos el resultado codificado en json a la página que lo llama
echo json_encode($resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

$result = $resultado->rowCount();
print_r($result);
```

when printing result, it prints 4 that is the correct result but the json_encode returns nothing and if i do 
    print_r($resultado->fetchAll());

it returns an empty array

Comment: The data must be in `utf-8`. Are you taking that into account? `var_dump($resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));`

Comment: OK when i try that, it print me the array. I think the json_encode it was is not working, why? do you have any idea? @zerkms

Comment: @Mariana Hernandez: have you read my comment entirely?

Comment: @cmorrissey: uhm, what? http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: yes @zerkms, my data is utf-8. I have the same data in a server and that code works, but in my local host it returns empty

Comment: @Mariana Hernandez: well, php insists it's not `utf-8`

Comment: how can i convert it there to utf-8? why is it working in the database of the server then? @zerkms

Comment: do you specify it's `utf-8` somewhere during connection?

Comment: No, the connection is just like in the code. Same as the code in the server @zerkms

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4361485/251311 - the charset must be specified **explicitly**

Comment: Thank you, that worked @zerkms. I wonder why it is working in that server, maybe the oho version. I will include it in the server code as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue happens because the returned data isn't encoded in `utf-8` as it is required by `json_encode`.

To fix it the `charset=utf8` attribute must be added to the PDO's DSN.