# GET charset with mysql PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is there a way of retrieving the current character set with PDO?
I used to have a little test with Mysqli to check if the forced character set was set by retrieving it like so:

```
$mysqli->get_charset();
```

That doesn't work on $conn = new PDO();

Any help is appreciated. I'm fairly new to PDO and trying to jump over from mysqli.

*P.s. i am aware how to set the character set, just want to test how to retrieve it.*

Thanks to HD answering the question I made his method static, perhaps its helpful for someone (I used some prior to 5.4 notation):

```
 public static function getCharset(PDO $objPdo) {      
  $objCharset = $objPdo->query("SELECT COLLATION('foo')");
  $charset = $objCharset->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
  return $charset[0];
 }
```

Comment: Interesting, I've never thought about it. I don't think there is a way to get the character set using PDO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Maybe OP means to use http://stackoverflow.com/a/4361485/ - Not sure if this falls under as a duplicate though. Having a hard time understanding the question.

Comment: Hi Fred, its not a duplicate as far as I'm concerned. My question is not about setting the character set, but "how" to "retrieve" the characterset with PDO just like the get_charset function with mysqli

Comment: @rinserepeat Which is why I said I was not sure. Thanks for the added info. See the answer given below.

Comment: @rinserepeat do not include the answer inside your question. It's Ok If you provide an answer to your own question as a separate answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we run the following MySQL query;

```
mysql> SELECT COLLATION('foo');
+-----------------------+
| COLLATION('foo')      |
+-----------------------+
| utf8_general_ci       |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set
```

So, we can use the following to get the charset

```
$objCharset = $objPdo->query("SELECT COLLATION('foo')");
echo $objCharset->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)[0]; //Output: utf8_general_ci
```

- [PDO Query](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)
- [PDO Fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)
- [Cubrid thread](http://www.cubrid.org/forum/718215)

You can then go a step further, and use the following (with object injection).

```
<?php 

class foo {
   public function get_charset($objPdo) {
      $objCharset = $objPdo->query("SELECT COLLATION('foo')");
      return $objCharset->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)[0];
   }
}

$objFoo = new foo();
$objPDO = new PDO(...);
echo $objFoo->get_charset($objPDO);
```

Comment: Hi HD that seems to work with a small modifaction for me: $objCharset = $conn->query("SELECT COLLATION('foo')");
$charset = $objCharset->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM); 
echo $charset[0];

Comment: Ah okay! The shorthand that is used in this answer was introduced in PHP5.5 (I believe) :)

Comment: sidenote: actually _dereference_ on functions are already on PHP 5.4 and above

Comment: @Ghost Thanks! I'll try remember that now

Comment: If you want the actual *charset* (not collation) use `SELECT CHARSET('');` instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the actual *charset* (not collation) you can do this:

```
$charset = $pdo->query("SELECT CHARSET('')")->fetchColumn();
if($charset === 'utf8mb4') {
    $charset = 'utf8';
}
```

I put the `utf8mb4` check in there because it's not compatible with PHP's `mb_` functions.