# MySQL won't load on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I can't get mysql table to load on localhost. below i used PDO and the table worked fine. no errors...the table works fine in phpmyAdmin...please help driving me nuts. i imported table from my web server to local host from a earlier version..

```
<?php

$user = "root";
$pass = "root";

try {
     $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=iosLeads',$user,$pass);
     foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from Customer') as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  print "Error! :" . $e->getMessage()."<br/>";
  die();
}

?>
```

but when i used this code it show a blank screen, no errors..i tried same code with other tables and it works fine.

```
<?php

        // set up the connection variables
        $db_name  = 'iosLeads';
        $hostname = 'localhost';
        $username = 'root';
        $password = 'root';

        // connect to the database
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);

        // a query get all the records from the users table
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM Customer';

        // use prepared statements, even if not strictly required is good practice
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );

        // execute the query
        $stmt->execute();

        // fetch the results into an array
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

        // convert to json
        $json = json_encode( $result );

        // echo the json string
        echo $json;
?>
```

I'm getting this in my php error.log

[17-Dec-2014 03:39:55 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:8888' (20)' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iosLeads/iosCustomerError.php:10
Stack trace:

## 0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iosLeads/iosCustomerError.php(10): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'root')

## 1 {main}

thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iosLeads/iosCustomerError.php on line 10
[17-Dec-2014 03:40:00 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:8888' (20)' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iosLeads/iosCustomerError.php:10
Stack trace:

## 0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iosLeads/iosCustomerError.php(10): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'root')

## 1 {main}

thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iosLeads/iosCustomerError.php on line 10
[17-Dec-2014 03:40:23 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:8888' (20)' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iosLeads/iosCustomerError.php:10
Stack trace:

## 0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iosLeads/iosCustomerError.php(10): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'root')

## 1 {main}

thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iosLeads/iosCustomerError.php on line 10

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` In addition add error reporting to your PDO statements.

Comment: Both codes are correct, I feel issue is something else

Comment: The code does look fine, adding error reporting can help us get to the problem @RamSharma

Comment: Yes, you are right it would help to find out the issue

Comment: @peter Balsamo, just try to check that table name is `Customer` or `customer`.

Comment: jay i'm confused as to where i put error reporting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the array in $result has strings other than UTF-8 encoded, the function json_encode() may fail and will return `false` (see [PHP manual json_encode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php)). To check this, dump the value of $result before using json_encode():

```
var_dump($result);
```

If you have an array in $result but no other return value than `false` from json_encode(), you must set the correct character encoding for the database connection.

Comment: Henrik how do i go about this "you must set the correct character encoding for the database connection".

Comment: @PeterBalsamo See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4361485/4137828) for how to set the character encoding.