# insert arabic using PDO is not working

Tags: php, android, mysql, pdo

i have dig very deep in this and view a lot of questions and that's not working 
every time i try to insert arabic it's showing like this (?????)

**Database Connection**

```
$db = new PDO( 
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=addme', 
    'root', 
    'a', 
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
);
```

**Inserting Page**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<?php

include("config.php");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$about = $_POST['about'];
$category = $_POST['category'];

$theId = "";
$date = round(microtime(true) * 1000);


$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(id,username,about,date,category) VALUES(
    :field1,
    :field2,
    :field3,
    :field4,
    :field5)
");
$stmt->execute(
    array(':field1' => $theId, 
        ':field2' => $name, 
        ':field3' => $about, 
        ':field4' => $date,
        ':field5' => $category));
$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();

        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Added You.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
```

**Database Encoding**

```
utf8_general_ci
```

The values from android app posting it.
The arabic post was working very fine using MySQL connection 
and after decide to use PDO this problem show up.

Comment: set the charset on the data source name http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361459/php-pdo-charset-set-names

Comment: @Ghost it didn't work either

Answer (score 1):

replace this part of code with yours I haven't tested but should work

```
$db = new PDO( 
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=addme;charset=utf8', 
    'root', 
    'a')
);
```

[image]

Comment: it didn't work also it messed up this function `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` i use it in another pages to get results

Comment: @YoussefAlSubaihi I have updated my answer can you try once again I have tested it worked for me attached screenshot

Comment: it didn't work, im sorry but it still inserting ???? as values i don't know why, when i were using MySQL it was working fine