# UTF 8 encoding not working properly in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, utf8-decode

I am trying to print data from MySql database.

I have a simple problem it is showing `D�lar` instead of `Dólar` .

Although I have included

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

In my html page so can any one help me out with this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: problem may be that your database has another charset for taht database / table

Comment: UTF 8 encoding not working properly in *your* PHP *script*... Because UTF-8 works perfectly in PHP, if you use it correctly.

Comment: in case of ajax response you have to set in content-type  var jax = createAjax();
jax.open("POST",path,true)  
jax.setRequestHeader('Content-type','text/html; charset=utf-8');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character set needs to be defined in a few different places:

#### The MySQL database

The text stored in the database might not be encoded as UTF-8. You can define a default character set as part of the [`create database`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html) statement:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

You can also specify per-column character sets with [`create table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html).

#### Within your PHP code

You'll need to tell your client-side code which encoding it should use when communicating with the database.

If you're using **PDO**, you can specify the character set [as part of the DSN string](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php):

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
```

If you're using **MySQLi**, you can use the [`mysqli_set_charset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) function/method:

```
$dbh->set_charset('utf8');
```

or:

```
mysqli_set_charset($dbh, 'utf8');
```

Alternatively, the MySQL website suggests [issuing a statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-syntax.html) after connecting to the server:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
```

#### Within the HTML output

For HTML5, you can simply add the following `<meta>` tag within the `<head>` element of your output:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: so with the statement issuing a statement is like I will execute SET NAMES 'utf8' ; ??

Comment: Yes, just run `SET NAMES 'utf8';` as an SQL statement once you've connected to the database, in the same way as you would run `SELECT * FROM x` or similar. I'd personally suggest using one of the other methods, though. **EDIT:** [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4361485/4200092) might be useful.

Comment: thanks bro Yeah I tried this but its not working , unluckily okay I will use the other method .

Answer (score 0):

I've used bellow function and its working for me

call_user_func_array('mb_convert_encoding', array(&$str,'HTML-ENTITIES','UTF-8'));