# PHP encoding in utf-8 and json_encode

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have this character `Œ` which is encoded in `iso-8859-1` (latin1_swedish_ci) in database. I want to convert it into `utf-8` to use in `json_encode`

```
$name = 'CŒUR'; //in iso-8859-1

$data = array('name' => utf8_encode($name));

echo json_encode($data);
```

Displayed:

```
{
    "name":"C\u008cUR"
}
```

Expected:

```
{
    "name":"C\u0152UR"
}
```

Then I get the response using AJAX, convert it into json object then display it on the page.

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/131dq8h0/3/)

The 2nd one is the expected result, you can check in the console.

Test link [Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ab1d7fcd6edf0bfffc226b2082c299c1702c436f)

Question: I want it to convert into `\u0152` to display it correctly in my page but I don't know why it is converted into `\u008c` instead

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: I cannot convert into \u0152 correctly

Comment: Œ doen't exist in ISO-8859-1. It's a Windows-1252 character. Besides, latin1 for MySQL is not ISO-8859-1 but Windows-1252. Replace `utf8_encode($name)` by `iconv('CP1252', 'UTF-8', $name)` or, better, just ask MySQL to return results set directely encoded in utf8 instead of latin1 (the SET NAMES equivalent - for PDO it's the parameter named *charset* of the DSN since PHP 5.3.6).

Comment: But in my database, in phpmyadmin it shows correctly `Œ` and if I do an `echo 'Œ'` directly, it shows correctly in my web page, in iso8859-1 charset

Comment: Indeed, convert enconding from MYSQL helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand it correctly it seems like you are recieving data in wrong charset from the database?
[Set charset to the data recieved from PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361459/php-pdo-charset-set-names)

Comment: I used `mysql_set_charset('utf8')` to return UTF-8 data and it solves my problem, thanks. Seems like converting it using PHP encode or decode can't work