# MySQL: Special chars and umlauts broken after exporting/importing dump?

Tags: mysql, import

I built a website locally using xampp. Now I want to put it on my server. I uploaded the code and now its time to import the database. So I exported it locally on the command line using:

```
mysqldump -hlocalhost -udb123456  -p123456 db123456 -e --default-character-set=utf8 > backup.sql
```

Now I created a new database on the server and imported this file using phpmyadmin on the server. The char set was set to utf-8 in phpmyadmin. When I open my site now, special chars like `ü` or `€` are shown as `Ã¼` for example.

I can not import the dump using a console on the server, I may only use phpmyadmin.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure the original db was in utf8?

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure

Comment: what about the meta tag of your site? maybe you have a different charset there?

Comment: @nowhere - I have the same problem. I added <meta charset="UTF-8"> to the page, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solved it in the PHP code, as described here

[PHP PDO: charset, set names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361459/php-pdo-charset-set-names)

(assuming you use PDO)