# ms access set charset utf-8 using pdo

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

I have a problem that made me crazy. 

I connect to Access by this code:

```
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$db_name; Uid=; Pwd=;"); 
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

---

When I want to **insert** data to access, data will be stored like Ú©Ø§Ù„Ø§.
How can I set the charset to **utf8**??

I have tried some solutions but could not solve my problem.

Comment: and what are those solutions?

Comment: try this: `$db->query('SET NAMES utf8');`

Comment: i have tried this but not works :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP PDO: charset, set names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361459/php-pdo-charset-set-names)

Comment: @Option  no doesnt work :(