# Define encoding when using PDO ODBC SQL Server connection?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, odbc

I connect to a SQL Server using like this:

```php
$pdo = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER=$serverName;DATABASE=$dbName", $username, $password);
```

The `PDO` instance is created, and I can run SQL queries with it, but sometimes I get charset related errors.

The database collation is non unicode (latin2), and I would like to get the response in UTF8. How is it possible to define it?

I was able to find some parameters like `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES ..."` but those are not available here, because I have an SQL Server.

Comment: You could use `nvarchar`, that supports full Unicode

Comment: I can not change the column definitions

Comment: Then what do you expect? These are not PHP errors, SQL Server is telling you that it simply cannot store that data in a `varchar` column with that collation, it is impossible. What exactly was the charset error, and how did it happen (what code causes it)?.

Comment: @Charlieface We used the old `mssql_` functions before, and everything worked well with it. The tables were filled from php using `mssq_`. Now we upgrade to PHP 7, and our only option is PDO with the ODBC SQL Server driver. If I list the contents of that table in SQL Server Management Studio, I can see all the rows without an error. So the error must be with the new driver, but I have no idea how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to try as below to add Client_CSet=UTF-8; to your connection code.

```
$pdo = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER=$serverName;DATABASE=$dbName;Client_CSet=UTF-8;Server_CSet=Windows-1251", $username, $password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only you need add `charset=utf8` in `dns` varible.
You can try this configuration:

```
$dns = "odbc:DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER=$serverName;DATABASE=$dbName;charset=utf8"

$pdo = new PDO($dns, $username, $password);
```

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361459/php-pdo-charset-set-names). Hope help you.